# Check Login only for particular jsp (Google Web application SDK)

Tags: authentication, filter

From what I've read, the general way of checking if the user is logged in is creating a filter method within the servlet. However, I want to check if the user is logged in ONLY IF when he tries to enter a particular jsp file. For example, when he is in the mainpage.jsp, I don't care if he's logged in or not but I only care only when he clicks on the link to hello.jsp that is displayed in mainpage.jsp. I'm not sure how to apply filter within the servlet only to a particular jsp. My code for checking if the user is logged in is as follows:

```
UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
user = userService.getCurrentUser();
if (user == null) {
        resp.sendRedirect(userService.createLoginURL(req.getRequestURI()));
}
```

thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You apply a filter on the web.xml file; see this link
http://brendangraetz.wordpress.com/2010/06/17/use-servlet-filters-for-user-authentication/